# javascript : In For loop pushing the value into the array variable, but values get appended(push) with undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 if (objJson[0].task.length > 0) {

                    var Arrayset = [];
                    var categories = [];
                    var starts1 = [];
                    var ends1 = [];
                    var val1 = [];
                    var val2 = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < objJson[0].task.length; i++) {

                        var syearval = parseInt(objJson[0].PSDate[i].substr(0, 4));
                        var smonthval = parseInt(objJson[0].PSDate[i].substr(5, 2));
                        var sdateval = parseInt(objJson[0].PSDate[i].substr(8, 2));

                        var eyearval = parseInt(objJson[0].PEDate[i].substr(0, 4));
                        var emonthval = parseInt(objJson[0].PEDate[i].substr(5, 2));
                        var edateval = parseInt(objJson[0].PEDate[i].substr(8, 2));



                       val1=[Date.UTC(syearval, smonthval, sdateval)];

                       val2= [Date.UTC(eyearval, emonthval, edateval)];


                       starts1.push(val1[i]);
                       ends1.push(val2[i]);

                       Arrayset.push({ name: objJson[0].task[i], completed: objJson[0].taskpercent[i], start:starts1[i], end:ends1[i] });


                    }

                    MainLoadChart(Arrayset);
                }

            }
```

Declared two array variable **starts1** and **ends1**.

For loop when **i=0**

starts1=[1574035200000]
ends1=[1574640000000]

values get added correctly in the array.

same thing, for loop gets iterated (i.e) when **i=1** etc

starts1=[1574035200000, **undefined**]
ends1=[1574640000000,**undefined**]

In **starts1** and **ends1** array undefined gets added in the array. I tried in all the ways and i am unable to fix to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i = 1

Your val1 will have only 1 value in array same for val2 i.e. array will have only 1 element

And you are pushing index value which will be `undefined`

How about

Instaed of

```
starts1.push(val1[i]);
ends1.push(val2[i]);
```

Use

```
starts1.push(val1[0]);
ends1.push(val2[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with assignment of `val1` and `val2`. You are repeatedly assigning a new array with 1 item to it, that's why there is value at index 0(when i=0) and `undefined` for index 1, 2,3 .. and so on.

You can actually skip this declaration & assignments of `val1, val2` and directly push values to array.

```
    //val1=[Date.UTC(syearval, smonthval, sdateval)];
    //val2= [Date.UTC(eyearval, emonthval, edateval)];


      starts1.push(Date.UTC(syearval, smonthval, sdateval));
      ends1.push(Date.UTC(eyearval, emonthval, edateval));
```